# How do you tell rails to generate integration tests using rspec and webrat?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, webrat

I'm working through the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec%3aintegration_tests) and I'm getting stuck on the integration tests. When I try to generate the integration tests for layout_links, I get the following comments in the generated test:

```
# Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat methods/matchers
```

And I don't see the "response.should be_success" syntax that I expect. I think I've managed to hose my installation somehow but I don't know how to see which gems I have on the system and how to uninstall/reinstall them.

[edit]I do have webrat configured in the "test" section of my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
      gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0'
end

group :test do
      gem 'rspec', '2.5.0'
      gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that message means that webrat was not detected when the scaffold was generated. Look in your projects `Gemfile` for:

`gem 'webrat'`

Add it if it's missing, then run `bundle install`, then run the generator again.

Comment: Thanks. I posted my Gemfile to the original question so that everyone can see it. I do include webrat in the test section which has worked for me before.

Comment: The generators are run in the development environment, so `webrat` needs to go there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this to work and the problem seems to be my ruby/rails installation. I'm running Ubuntu and I think I've mixed a few packages installed via apt with those installed via bundle and gotten my system confused. I've followed this [tutorial on installing Ruby on Rails in Ubuntu using rvm](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2010/09/01/How-to-install-Rails-3.0-and-Ruby-1.9.2-on-Ubuntu) and now I can generate and run my tests again. I'm still having a few issues with autotest which I believe are related to conflicting packages. rvm looks like it's a much better way to set up a rails environment than apt and it allows you to only install your rails environment for one user. This way, you can set up a test user to make sure you get everything configured correctly without changing your entire system.

Thanks for all of the help.